# Hashable abstract class from abc module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read about the abc module by reading chapter two of "Fluent Python". So I started writing some code just to play with it. Why is an empty class an instance of the abstract base class Hashable?

```
from collections import abc

class foo:
    pass

print(isinstance(foo,abc.Hashable)) # True
```

Comment: Because every object has a `__hash__()` slot wrapper. Check with `"__hash__" in dir(foo)`. Abstract classes are just that - define the abstract behavior of objects based on a certain property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `isinstance(foo, abc.Hashable)` does is check that your object has a  `__hash__` method, this is what Python calls to hash an object. A class is itself an `object` and thus inherit the `object.__hash__` method.

```
class Foo:
    pass

isinstance(Foo, object) # True
Foo.__hash__ # <slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'object' objects>

hash(Foo) # -9223371900938361605
```

Comment: Thanks makes sense, I should have known this.